# Even though my xpath is correct I am getting error as org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, web-application

I'm unable to click on **Plus** button and **Minus** button.
My xpath is as `//div[4]/span[2]`

Even though my xpath is correct, I am getting an exception.
I have also synced it using waits.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ziprooms.min.css">
<head>
<body>
<div class="zr-container">
<div class="ng-scope" autoscroll="true" ng-view="">
<header class="ng-scope" scrolldata="" waypoint="">
<div class="header-home">
<div class="zr-loginBox ng-scope ng-hide" ng-show="modalbox" ng-include="'templates/loginbox.html'">
<div class="zr-login ng-scope ng-hide" validation="" ng-show="signinbox">
<div class="zr-signup ng-scope ng-hide" validateup="" ng-show="signupbox">
<h4>
<form class="clearfix ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-email" novalidate="" ng-class="{'submitted': submitted2}" method="post" name="signup">
<label>
<label>
<label>
<label>
<label>
<label>
<input class="zr-book" type="submit" ng-click="submitted2=true; signupotp();" value="Sign Up" title="Sign Up" name="signup">
</label>
</form>
<p>
</div>
<div class="zr-fpwd ng-scope ng-hide" validatef="" ng-show="fpwdbox">
</div>
<div class="zr-overlay"></div>
<div class="zr-logo">
<div class="zr-contact">
<div id="videoContent">
<div class="zr-blueStrip">
<form class="clearfix ng-pristine ng-valid" date-cal="">
<div class="zr-zip-25">
<div class="zr-zip-15">
<div class="zr-zip-15">
<div class="zr-zip-15">
<span class="icon-minus" ng-click="minus('guest')"></span>
<input id="guest" class="zr-search" type="text" style="text-align:center" value="1 Guest" readonly="" name="guest">
<span class="icon-plus" ng-click="plus('guest')"></span>
</div>
<div class="zr-zip-15">
<div class="zr-zip-search">
</form>
</div>
</div>
</header>
<section class="zr-section-1 ng-scope">
<section class="zr-section-2 ng-scope">
<section class="zr-section-3 ng-scope">
<section class="zr-section-4 ng-scope">
</div>
<section class="zr-section-5 ng-scope" filtercity="" ng-include="'templates/seo.html'" ng-controller="TabController as tab">
<footer class="ng-scope" ng-include="'templates/footer.html'">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<script src="js/libs/angular.min.js">
<script src="js/libs/angular-route.min.js">
<script src="js/libs/angular-carousel.min.js">
<script src="js/libs/angular-touch.min.js">
<script src="js/libs/pikaday.min.js">
<script src="js/libs/angular-scroll.min.js">
<script src="js/app.min.js">
<div class="pika-single is-bound is-hidden" style="position: static; left: auto; top: auto;">
<div class="pika-single is-bound is-hidden" style="position: static; left: auto; top: auto;">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please share web driver code and html code of that button?

Comment: <div class="zr-zip-15">
<span class="icon-minus" ng-click="minus('guest')"></span>
<input id="guest" class="zr-search" type="text" style="text-align:center" value="1 Guest" readonly="" name="guest">
<span class="icon-plus" ng-click="plus('guest')"></span>
</div>

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below xpath. Its more **dynamic** and less **fragile**.

Also the xpath you are using seems to be incorrect. It doesn't seem to be the fourth div.

If you are using a relative div (eg. //div) and a unique path ahead (like your are using span with a unique class name) then you don't need to give a number(sequence number) with the div.

**for plus button** - `//span[@class = 'icon-minus']`

**for minus button**- `//span[@class = 'icon-plus']`

Comment: (//span[@class = 'icon-minus'])[1]
this is my xpath